# Text localization in iPhone apps that use openGL?

Tags: iphone, opengl, text

I'm writting an small game in iPhone, and I'm being asked to add in-game text will be localized in EFIGS+J+Chinese Simplified and provided to me later.

Which tools and methods are avaiable in OpenGL ES for the iphone in order to render text  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do realize that you can combine openGl with other drawing mechanisms, which could handle text and especially localized text easier?  An openGL app doesn't mean you can only use openGL to draw to the screen.  For example, you could have an overlay view that is not openGL, right on top of an openGL view, providing you with the localized text support that you need.

Comment: For a good tutorial, see: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/04/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-1-basic.html

Comment: @mahboudz I know it's 2014 but do you know where I can find some information on the topic of combining opengl with other rendering mechanisms, by any chance do you know how MMO games typically support unicode chat system? Thanks.